# Threadpool and dynamicly changing number of workers

Tags: python, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Lets say I want to to implement this code but the MAIN a differences are :

1. I dont know what is the max_workers value.
2. My workers must work in parallel.
3. My number of workers are changing dynamicly.

I thought about making a queue of workers and by that keep pushing tasks to the available worker but
I dont know how to do / implement it.
Thank you very much.
I hope my question is clear.

```py
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
   'http://www.cnn.com/',
   'http://europe.wsj.com/',
   'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
   'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

def load_url(url, timeout):
   with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout = timeout) as conn:
   return conn.read()

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 5) as executor:

   future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
   for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
   url = future_to_url[future]
   try:
      data = future.result()
   except Exception as exc:
      print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
   else:
      print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```

Comment: what is the rule by which you want to scale workers ?

Answer (score -1):

You can take the number or urls divided by 10 as the  max workers identifier, since their count impacts the count of jobs you are going to submit:

```
max_workers = URLS//10
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment I think I have found my answer here https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html
Changed in version 3.5: If max_workers is None or not given, it will default to the number of processors on the machine, multiplied by 5, assuming that
 ThreadPoolExecutor is often used to overlap I/O instead of CPU work and the number of workers should be higher than the number of workers for ProcessPoolExecutor.